# Calculation based on class name in SASS

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I am using SASS and Angular 6. I have class name `level` that is generated in javascript with dynamic suffix, for example `level-1` or `level-10`.
I want to calculate padding in `scss` file depends on that suffix.
Should be something like this:

level-$ {
  padding-left: calc($*10)px
}

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is, you can write a loop in SASS to generate the classes, like this for example.

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .levels-#{$i} {
    padding-left: 10px * $i;
  }
}
```

Comment: I found this solution too, but it is not perfect, because i don't know how many classes i should generate. But i understand that this is closest solution. Or i must use inline styles

Comment: @mr__brainwash it generates the number of classes you place where the "10" sits.